# Работа с массивом координат в NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Хочу полученные координаты попарно записать в массив **NumPy** и потом их обработать. Делаю так:

```
#создаю массив с одним элементом т.к. как создать пустой массив нужной структуры так и не понял
arrayXY = np.array((1,1), dtype=int)

#тут получаю массив нужных координат
...
(yCoords, xCoords) = np.where(res >= threshold)
...
#сохраняем полученные координаты в массив
for (x, y) in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
        arrayXY = np.append(arrayXY, (x, y))

#тут пытаюсь обработать полученные координаты
for xs,ys in arrayXY:
        print(xs, ys)
```

Но код не работает. Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\+out\test.py", line 34, in <module>
    for xs,ys in arrayXY:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object
```

Comment: а что у вас представляет собой `res`?

Comment: Честно говоря, вообще не очень понятно, что у вас происходит в коде. Попробуйте выводить на печать всё, что у вас получается после каждого шага.
Возможно, тогда вы сами поймёте, что происходит.

Comment: res = cv2.matchTemplate(target, tpl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.87
(yCoords, xCoords) = np.where(res >= threshold)
Мне нужно (yCoords, xCoords) сохранить в массив, а потом по парно обработать

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять элементы в массив нужно так:

```
arrayXY = np.append(arrayXY, [[x, y]], axis = 0)
```

а создавать:

```
arrayXY = np.ndarray(shape=(0,2), dtype=int)
```